# How do I return a random variable with switch case in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
    switch(rand){
        case 1:
         System.out.println(ao); 
         break;
        case 2:
         System.out.println(pf);// print your array
            break;
        case 3:
         System.out.println(iff);
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println(ie);
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println(pt);
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println(pn);
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println(ptt);
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println(mt);
            break;

        case 9:
            System.out.println(tt);

            break;
        case 10:
            System.out.println(it);
            break;
        case 11:
           System.out.println(pv);
            break;
        case 12:
            System.out.println(is);
            break;
        case 13:
            System.out.println(to);
            break;
        case 14:
            System.out.println(pvii);
            break;
        case 15:
            System.out.println(pe);
            break;
        case 16:
            System.out.println(mo);
            break;
        case 17:
            System.out.println(ivii);
            break;

        case 18:
            System.out.println(in);
            break;
        case 19:
           System.out.println(rin);
            break;
        case 20:
            System.out.println(rivii);
            break;
        case 21:
          System.out.println(rao);
         break;
        case 22:
        System.out.println(rpf);
            break;
        case 23:
        System.out.println(rif);
            break;

        case 24:
            System.out.println(rie);
            break;

        case 25:
            System.out.println(rpt);
            break;
        case 26:
            System.out.println(rpn);
            break;
        case 27:
            System.out.println(rptt);
            break;
        case 28:
            System.out.println(rmt);
            break;

        case 29:
            System.out.println(rtt);
            break;
        case 30:

System.out.println(rit);
            break;
        case 31:
            System.out.println(rpv);
            break;
        case 32:
            System.out.println(riss);
            break;
        case 33:
            System.out.println(rto);
            break;
        case 34:
            System.out.println(rpvii);
            break;
        case 35:
            System.out.println(rpe);
            break;
        case 36:
            System.out.println(rmo);
            break;


}
    return null;


}
```

Each variable in the cases has its own value. I now need the program to return any random variable from the cases each time I run it, because these values have to be stored in a database. How do I do it?

Comment: Use an map with the rand value as the key.

Comment: How exactly should i do it? Can you help me out?

Comment: Start making the distinction between values and variables.

Comment: If you only need the value, then you can just return it instead of printing it. Your function will then pick a value. If you want to know what variable was selected and want to work with it you better use an array or a map, so you can remeber the index/key.

Answer (score 1):

Add your variable to an `ArrayList` or an `Array`.

After that you can get a random element from the list:

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(arrayList.size());

System.out.println(arrayList.get(index));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this, but it seems like you are doing it wrong...
Anyway, I'm not sure if you want to return the rand value or a different random value.

If you want to return the `rand` value, just return it in the end, instead of returning null.

Now, if you want to return a value inside the case, you can call it inside each of them, and the function will end right there:

```
switch(rand){
    case 1:
     System.out.println(ao);
     return Math.random();
    case 2:
     System.out.println(pf);
     return Math.random();
    (...)
```

Now, you can work down the value returned by Math.random()